# methods in Java will not work?

Tags: java, oop, methods

So I'm learning Java in class and I'm really loving it so far but its really hard to understand sometimes. Right now I'm trying to understand how methods work. My question is why my code is not working. I am trying to read in an integer from user input then square it.

Here is my code:

```
package freetime;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class methods {

    public static void main(String []args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println( " enter a number ");
        int number = input.nextInt();
        square(number);
    }

    public static int square(int number){
        int num;
        num = number * number;
        return (num);
    }
}
```

Let's say I input 5 on the console, the program immediately terminates and I cannot figure out why.

Comment: What happens to the value your `square()` method returns? You're not printing it.

Comment: It's actually working I think :-) You're reading a number from console, finding a square of that number but you're not doing anything useful with the result, so do a println of your result in your main method :-)

Comment: There is no statement after square(number) method in your main function thus the program immediately terminates.

Comment: Yo are not making use of the return value from the method. Therefore you do not know what happened

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by others, you don't print the value and the console will close as soon as the program ends. So you could try something like this

```
public class ScannerTest {
    public static void main(String []args){
        while(true){
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println( " enter a number (-1 to stop)");
            int number = input.nextInt();
            if(number == -1){
                break;
            }
            int output = square(number);
            System.out.println(output); 
        }
    }

    public static int square(int number){
        int num;
        num = number * number;
        return (num);
    }
}
```

This will print the result and loop ask for new input as long as you don't stop the program.

Comment: I'm confused, because it seems like this solution doesn't make use of the second method.

Comment: I edited to make the individual steps visible... whether you assign the result of square(number) to output and print output or you print the square(number) directly does not make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, when main method comes to end and if there aren't any non-deamon threads running, the JVM ends. Your program came to an end without printing out the result of the `square()` call.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*here is your solution :*/



import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/*in java everything has to be in a class */
class SquareNumber
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println( " enter a number ");
    int number = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println(square(number));
 /*something to print the squared number*/
    }

    public static int square(int number){
    int num;
    num = number * number;
    return (num);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program is terminated because there is no other statement after `square(number);` statement. So your program executes `square(...)` method and after then it found end of main function so the program is terminated. To see some output you must print result of `square(...)` method.

```
package freetime; 
import java.util.Scanner; 
public class methods {

public static void main(String []args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println( " enter a number ");
    int number = input.nextInt();

    int result=square(number);//executing square(...) method and store the returned value of square method to result variable 
    System.out.println("Square of "+number+" is : "+ result);//printing result 

}

public static int square(int number){
    int num;
    num = number * number;
    return (num);


}

}
```